# Database not updating from Ajax POST

Tags: php, sql, sql-update

I have a JS function that is creating multiple "draggables" and is then collecting 3 variables for all "drags" and AJAX POSTing then to my update.php file
The JS functions are working correctly because on sending the data my alert is advising me of the "new" outputs
But I can not get the database to update the x_pos and y_pos for the various ids in the table aa_test.
Here is the code-

```
<?php
        include ('dbconnect.php');
        $con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME);
if( isset( $_POST['id'] ) ){
    if( is_array( $_POST['id'] ) ){
        foreach( $_POST['id'] as $id ){
            if( isset( $_POST['x-' . $id] ) && isset( $_POST['y-' . $id] )){
                echo "ID:" . $id;
                echo "X:" . $_POST['x-' . $id];
                echo "Y:" . $_POST['y-' . $id];
        $query = " UPDATE aa_test SET   
            x_pos=$['x-' . $id], 
            y_pos =$['y-' . $id] 
            WHERE id=$id ";
        $myUpdate = mysqli_query($con, $query);
            }
        }
    }
}else{
    echo 'NO ID';
}
```

Comment: Use error reporting. You also are open to SQL injections. Concatenation doesn't exist in double quotes. `$['x-' . $id]` <> `$_POST['x-' . $id]` and wouldnt function the same if it were.

Comment: user3783243, Thanks. Youve told me what the solution is not. Any chance of sharing what the answer is?

Comment: @user3783243 the affore mentioned point is quite valid however .. that syntax will very likely not produce the output you want. Either way: Try running mysqli_error($con) before your close statement and check the output

Comment: mysqli_error is Error Description : "" However Apache has 2 error line  "insufficient configuration info to establish database link" and "child spawned but unable to open database link"

Comment: is the output of mysqli_connect_error() empty as well? If yes and mod_log_sql is active I suggest disabling it in your Apache config

Comment: Ive checked all error logs and the DC connevtion is OK. The problem is clearly how Im defining the variables$query = " UPDATE aa_test SET   
            x_pos=$['x-' . $id], 
            y_pos =$['y-' . $id] 
            WHERE id=$id ";

Answer (score 0):

Putting the variables in curly brackets {} fixed the problem